# Что делать, если не работает bias, если задавать программно?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Программно пытаюсь задать bias, чтобы мои чекбоксы равномерно растянулись по контейнеру. Каждый чекбокс между собой соединил. Вот кусочек кода:

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(mainConstraintLayout)

constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox1.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox2.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox3.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox4.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox5.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox6.id, 0.5F)
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(checkBox7.id, 0.5F)

constraintSet.applyTo(mainConstraintLayout)
```

В итоге получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А необходимо так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему программная реализация не работает как в xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено спустя час))

В коде в одном месте неправильно указал одному чекбоксу привязку, из за этого всё слетело. Починил.

Но! Ещё пришлось дописать одну плюшку, без которой все чекбоксы сдвигались равномерно вправо))

```
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox1.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox2.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox3.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox4.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox5.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox6.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(checkBox7.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
```

Возможно, это будет кому-то полезно :)